# How many tangent lines to the curve $y = \frac{x}{x+1}$ pass through the point $(1,2)$?

Tags: calculus

**The question**:
How many tangent lines to the curve $y = \frac{x}{x+1}$ pass through the point $(1,2)$? At which points do these tangent lines touch the curve?

**My attempt**:
To find the slope of the tangent line to the curve, we need to get the first derivative of $y = \frac{x}{x+1}$, which is $y' = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$.

So, the line equation of the tangent line is $y = m(x-1) + 2$, where $m = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$ for the given $x$.

We also know that the point where the tangent line intersects the curve must be both on the tangent line and the curve, so using that,

$$\frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{x-1}{(x+1)^2} + 2$$

$$\frac{x-1}{(x+1)^2} + 2 - \frac{x}{x+1} = 0$$

$$\frac{x - 1 + 2x^2 + 4x + 2 - x^2}{(x+1)^2} = 0$$

$$\frac{x^2 + 5x + 1}{(x+1)^2} = 0$$

And I'm stuck. I'd appreciate if you can point out where I'm wrong and how to better approach this problem.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $(x+1)^2$ and you get $x^2 + 5x + 1 = 0\cdot (x+1)^2 = 0$.

Comment: When finding a common denominator, what happened to your last term. $-\frac{x}{x+1}=-\frac{x(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}=-\frac{x^2+x}{(x+1)^2}$

Comment: Your numerator is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ to be equal to 0, we must have $a=0$. In this case we have $$x^2+4x+1=0$$ and the result follows.

EDIT:
Note that $$\frac{x-1}{(x+1)^2}+2-\frac{x}{x+1}=\frac{x^2+4x+1}{(x+1)^2}$$
You might wanna check your steps.

Comment: I somehow plugged this wrong into a quadratic equation solver and thought it has no roots, my bad, thanks!

Comment: @AniKhachatryan spotted a mistake in your steps as well and edited my answer, you might wanna take a look

Comment: "I somehow plugged this wrong into a quadratic equation solver and thought it has no roots,"  That would just mean that no tangent lines pass through $(1,2)$.  That's certainly possible.  If the question had been how many tangent lines pass through $(1,-2)$ you *would* get a quadratic with no real roots because there *aren't* any tangent lines that go throgh that point.

Comment: @fleablood two tangent lines pass through the point in fact

Comment: thank you, that was a sloppy mistake, @fleablood I had already looked up the answer, so I knew there were 2 lines

Comment: "two tangent lines pass through the point in fact " Do they?  For $x < -1$ whe have $f'(x) > 0$ and $f(x)>0$ so they can never pass through $(1,-2)$.  And for $0>x >-1$ we have $f'(x) > |x|$ as so none pass through is and for $f(x)>0$ we have $f'(x) > 0; f(x) >0$.

Comment: @fleablood the point is $(1,2)$

Comment: Right.  But had the point *been* $(1,-2)$ then there would be no lines passing through it.  I was responding to the comment that she had gotten a quadratic equation with no roots and conclude that must be an error.  .... that in and of itself is not an error.  If that were a correct result all that would mean is that no tangent lines go through the point in question.  So ***FOR EXAMPLE*** if the question had been to find the tangent lines through $(1,-2)$ there wouldn't be any and our quadratic equation would have no roots.  Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

The equation of the tangent line to the curve at the point $ (a,\frac{a}{a+1}) $ is

$$y=\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}(x-a)+\frac{a}{a+1}$$

it passes through the point $ (1,2) $ if

$$2=\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}(1-a)+\frac{a}{a+1}$$

So,
$$2(a+1)^2=(1-a)+a(a+1)$$

or

$$a^2+4a+1=0$$
thus
$$a=-2\pm \sqrt{3}$$